# . Помогите разобраться с Unity mask

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть панель с изображениями[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ставлю ui mask становится вот так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Искал решение проблемы, там все говорят, что с Image надо как-то работать, но я никак не пойму что надо делать. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: А что вы хотите что бы было, в чём собственно вопрос ?)

Comment: Тфу, самое главное не написал. Почему скрывает только панельку, а дочерние элементы нет?

Answer (score 0):

Всю информацию о масках вы можете найти на офф сайте
[Офф док](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-mask)

От себя добавлю, в вашем случае маска обрезала изображение по контуру panel(1)

Comment: А как сделать невидимыми элементы, которые дочерни панели Panel(1) и за пределами Panel?